# Same header and footer for every page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I have a problem with my header and my footer.

If I do that:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{img/header.png}}
\fancyfoot[L]{ Name Firstname - v1.0 \\  Date}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\  / \pageref{LastPage}}
```

Only the first page from a chapter uses this header and footer.

And if I do that:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}
{    
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{img/header.png}}
    \fancyfoot[L]{ Name Firstname - v1.0 \\  Date}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\  / \pageref{LastPage}}
}
```

Other page from a chapter uses this header and footer, but not the first.

How can I set that is the same for both?

Obviously if I put the two codes together, it's work, but I think it's heavy and not optimal...

edit :

I just tested this code (after i read the comment from Werner)

```
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{img/header.png}}
\fancyfoot[L]{ Name Firstname - v1.0 \\  Date}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\  / \pageref{LastPage}}
```

It's work for every page from a chapter, its fine !

But now i have a problem with my table of contents.

```
\tableofcontents{\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

This code product a table of content with my fancy header and footer. Strangely, the second page from my table of content is whiteout header and footer (as i want for my entire table).

Comment: which documentclass do you use?

Comment: I use the document class report.

Answer (score 8):

You need to set the page style to `plain` after redefining it using [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)'s `\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}` command. This is described in the [`fancyhdr` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) (section **7 Redefining `plain` style**, p 7-8):

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,lastpage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{fancyhdr,graphicx,lastpage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=5pt]{example-image-a}}% Right header
  \fancyfoot[L]{Name Firstname - v1.0 \\  Date}% Left footer
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\  / \pageref{LastPage}}% Right footer
}
\pagestyle{plain}% Set page style to plain.
```

This should set the page style to `plain` for the entire document, including the first page of `\chapter`s.

If you wish to have certain chapters to have a different (`empty`, say) page style, you would have to set this manually. For the `\tableofcontents` though, this is a bit tricky, since using

```
\thispagestyle{empty}\tableofcontents
```

or

```
\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{empty}
```

would set it to `empty` either too early, or perhaps too late, depending on the choice. This is because of the construction of the command `\tableofcontents` (from [`report.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls) - your document class):

```
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
```

Note that `\tableofcontents` executes `\chapter*`, which in itself initiates a page break via `\clearpage` (or `\cleardoublepage`, depending on your document class options, like `openright`). So one would have to insert the page style somewhere around the place where the ToC is being built... in this case, at `\@starttoc{toc}`. You can do this with an [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patch (there are other ways as well):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}% <cmd>
  {\@starttoc}% <search>
  {\thispagestyle{empty}\@starttoc}
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

Taking all of this into consideration, you might be after the following setup:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx,lastpage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,lastpage}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=5pt]{example-image-a.pdf}}% Right header
  \fancyfoot[L]{Name Firstname - v1.0 \\  Date}% Left footer
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\  / \pageref{LastPage}}% Right footer
}
\pagestyle{plain}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}% <cmd>
  {\@starttoc}% <search>
  {\thispagestyle{empty}\@starttoc}
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Of course, this could be changed (even improved) if you don't have a title, or if there was more information on your document structure.

Some references regarding the above usages:

- [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764)
- [`etoolbox` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) regarding command patching via `\patchcmd` (section **3.4 Patching**, p 11)

---

Some other things to consider:

- Using `\linewidth` if you wish to have a header image that spans the entire width of the text block (rather than `8cm`).
- Using the [`pageslts` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/pageslts) which provides a `VeryLastPage` label, depending on whether or not you have unprocessed floats at the end of your report.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Your solution work for my chapters.

But i have always a problem with my table of content. The first page is whiteout header and footer (empty), but the second page have the fancy header and footer (plain).

But, if a use this :
`\tableofcontents{\thispagestyle{empty}}`

It's work, my entire table is empty.

So...i think my problem is solved.

Comment: @Karim: Yes, adding `\thispagestyle{empty}` *after* `\tableofcontents` would make the final page *before* the next chapter `empty`. Indeed it may be required and seem clumsy in your code, but be necessary to make it work.