# Footer on EVERY page (including chapter*'s/ chapter's first page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I have the following problem: I want to have a footer on every page (even on the first pages of a chapter* or chapter, the tableofcontents, the bibliography as well as the acronyms page. I achieved to get footers on every second and following pages of a chapter using the post I found on [stackoverflow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109656/same-header-and-footer-for-every-page). Is there a simple possibility to get the footer on really EVERY page?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, DIV=calc, headings=small]{scrreprt}

    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}

    %Define footers
    \fancypagestyle{Whatever}{
      \fancyhf{} %Clear header/footer
      \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %No line in header area
      \fancyfoot[C]{Whatever \thepage} %Centered footer
    }

    \pagestyle{Whatever} %Set page style.

    \begin{document}
    \chapter*{Test1}
    \lipsum[1-8] % Filler Text

    \chapter*{Test2}
    \lipsum[1-8] % Filler Text
    \end{document}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{Whatever}`

Comment: I note that the document class is doing something behind the scenes, in terms of chapter definitions. That's why the code is necessary. A custom document class, which does not define chapters that way, might not need such code.

Comment: Yeah, that can be... But it works as expected :D

Answer (score 1):

Whole solution (Thank goes to [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, DIV=calc, headings=small]{scrreprt}

    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}

    %Define footers
    \fancypagestyle{Whatever}{
      \fancyhf{} %Clear header/footer
      \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %No line in header area
      \fancyfoot[C]{Whatever \thepage} %Centered footer
    }

    %Set page style
    \pagestyle{Whatever} %Set page style.
    \renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{Whatever} %New command

    \begin{document}
    \chapter*{Test1}
    \lipsum[1-8] % Filler Text

    \chapter*{Test2}
    \lipsum[1-8] % Filler Text
    \end{document}
```