# Footer ruler on first page in fancyhdr with `book`

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, books

I have a problem with the footer ruler on the first page of each chapter, it doesn't show whilst for the the second and following page of each chapter the ruler occurs.
I found the answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344092/44119 but this is for a `scrreprt` and I use `book`. In `book` the `\chapterpagestyle` does not exist.

The first page:

[image]

The subsequent pages:

[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}                                                                                                                 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhead[LE]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\fancyhead[CE]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[CO]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\fancyplain{\bfseries\thepage}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\fancyfoot[CE]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\fancyfoot[RE]{\fancyplain{\bfseries\scriptsize Generated }{\bfseries\scriptsize Generated }}
\fancyfoot[LO]{\fancyplain{\bfseries\scriptsize Generated }{\bfseries\scriptsize Generated }}
\fancyfoot[CO]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\fancyplain{\bfseries\thepage}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

So my question is how to solve this:

- what is the alternative for `\chapterpagestyle` in `book`

or

- how to directly solve it in the given MWE?

Comment: `\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancyplain}}` should work.

Comment: I replaced `\pagestyle{fancyplain}` at line 4 with `\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancyplain}}` it does show the footer ruler on the first page, but has as effect that I get a header on page 1, no footers on subsequent pages and the header ruler is gone at the pages 2 and further.

Comment: I didn't say to replace anything. Simply add it.

Comment: Sorry this was not clear from your comment, I now added `\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancyplain}}` after `\pagestyle{fancyplain}`, looks a bit better, but now I get a header on page 1 of the chapter, which  I wouldn't like to have.

Comment: Sorry it was unclear that you want only the footer. You probably can do `\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancyplain}\fancyhead{}}`. Basically you have to redefine plain style, see the fancyhdr documentation.

Comment: Looks to me that I now still get the ruler with the first page. I also tried @Bernard his answer, this looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the first page of a chapter is in the plain style, you have to redefine it. I took the opportunity to simplify the code for the fancyplain style:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}%
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
%%%
\fancypagestyle{fancyplain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE, RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO, RE]{\bfseries\scriptsize Generated}
}
%%%
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\textbf{\thepage}}
\fancyfoot[LO, RE]{\bfseries\scriptsize Generated}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}%

\begin{document}

\chapter{My Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks promising, have to test it in my bigger code base.

Comment: This works in my normal cases OK, though when I have a `\part` part I want to suppress the header and footer. I didn't yet succeed. I'll create a new issue for that problem.

Comment: You might add a `\thispagestyle{empty}` immediately after `\part`.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me, see my new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566056/footer-ruler-on-first-page-in-fancyhdr-with-book-but-not-in-part-part