# Footer ruler on first page in fancyhdr with `book` but not in `\part` part

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, books, parts

In the question [Footer ruler on first page in fancyhdr with `book`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566034/footer-ruler-on-first-page-in-fancyhdr-with-book) I asked about the possibility to get a footer ruler on the first page of a chapter. The answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/566047/44119 gave the required result for this problem.

I now have a similar problem, where I want to have the footer ruler and footer text on the first page of a chapter but when I have a `part` I don't want to have the footer ruler and footer text on that page.

The suggestion by @Bernard in comment on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/566047/44119 was to use `\thispagestyle{empty}` but thiis didn't work, so I thought using of a `\newenvironment` for this but this didn't work either (my try is commented out at the moment.
My MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
%
\fancypagestyle{fancyplain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE, RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO, RE]{\bfseries\scriptsize Generated}
}
%
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\textbf{\thepage}}
\fancyfoot[LO, RE]{\bfseries\scriptsize Generated}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}

\newenvironment{MyPart}{
  \fancyfoot[LO, RE]{}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}
}{
  \fancyfoot[LO, RE]{\bfseries\scriptsize Generated }
}

\begin{document}

%% test based on suggestion by @Bernard in comment on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/566047/44119:
\part{Manual}
\thispagestyle{empty}

%% my own idea:
\begin{MyPart}
\part{Manual}
\end{MyPart}

\chapter{My Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trouble is that also `\part` uses the `plain` page style, which you have redefined to suit your needs. Worse, `\part` does issue a `\newpage` in order to force an empty *verso* page; your manual `\thispagestyle{empty}` comes thus too late.

I think the only way here is to patch the definition of `\part`. Either copy/paste the original definition from `book.cls` in your preamble with the suitabile substitution

```
\renewcommand\part{%    <-- use \renewcommand here
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{empty}%   <-- empty instead of plain
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \null\vfil
  \secdef\@part\@spart}
```

or you let e.g. `xpatch` do the work for you

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\part}{plain}{empty}{}{}
```

A MWE based on your code with the second solution is

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\fancypagestyle{fancyplain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE, RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO, RE]{\bfseries\scriptsize Generated}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\textbf{\thepage}}
\fancyfoot[LO, RE]{\bfseries\scriptsize Generated}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\part}{plain}{empty}{}{}

\begin{document}

\part{Manual}

\chapter{My Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tested the `xpatch` solution for my case and this works as expected.

Comment: I have a subsequent question about the word "Part" that appears and for the second part (in my case it is appendices) I would like to remove the word "Part". I'd probably best create a new question for this...

Comment: Solved the removal of the "Part": `\renewcommand{\thepart}{}                                                                                                           \renewcommand{\partname}{}`

Answer (score 3):

Using `xpatch`  differently:

```
\usepackage{ xpatch} 
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@part}{#2}{#2\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

[image]